# What is an epistemic graph in AI and how is it related to cognitive science?

Tags: definitions, cognitive-science

I found this paper [Epistemic graphs for representing and reasoning with positive and negative influences of arguments](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370220300035).

I haven't found any definition of or Wikipedia article on epistemic graphs on the Internet.

Can anyone give me an introductory idea?

Comment: See this github for further [ref](https://github.com/alwilson/epistemic-graphs). Essentially EG assumes *degree of belief* as some probabilistic quantitative version for our usual qualitative everyday argument based on our axiomatic superstructural beliefs. Now in what degree you believe this core idea to be useful for what kind of applications?